# TRPC query based on dynamic url

Tags: typescript, next.js, trpc.io, t3

Using TRPC and Next JS I want to query a single post based on a dynamic url without using SSR or SSG. Only method I found to work is to add `as string` to `router.query.id` but this results in a TRPC error (the error only occurs on the first load), because `router.query.id` is an empty object for the initial load not a string. Is there a way to do this without the initial TRPC error?

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";

const SinglePost = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data } = api.post.getById.useQuery({
    id: router.query.id as string,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SinglePost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my query like this:

```
const { data } = api.post.getById.useQuery(
    {
      id: router.query.id as string,
    },
    { enabled: !!router.query.id}
  );
```

so it will only start when `router.query.id` is not an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess having a default value may be enough in your case

```
  const defaultId = 'blah/blah/blah'
  const { data } = api.post.getById.useQuery({
    id: router.query.id ?? defaultId,
  });
```

Comment: Is it possible to only start the query when useRouter returned the actual query?